# Image link block takes up whole width of the page

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, block

I have a main `div` as a container with a width of 90%.  Inside at the top, I have a title (image) with `height: 5em`, `display: block`, and `margin: auto`.

My HTML code is set up like so: `<a href=""><img scr=""></a>`.

When I click way to the left of the picture, I am still able to click on the link.  **I am using Chrome for this**.  I tested this in **Safari** and **Firefox**; same result.  **IE** and **Opera** only registered the link when my mouse was directly over the picture (which is what I want).  I'm hoping I can get what I want in *all* browsers.  Thanks.

**Edit**: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bionicrm/dXaAF/.

Comment: What code should I post?

Comment: The code that you are talking about and preferably a working example at jsfiddle or similar

Comment: try to set the width of the link to a little percentage by css, so that the link will fit the image dimension and nothing more. like a{ width:5%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/K7Vwd/

You can put a wrapper around the entire thing specifying the size you want shown:

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap"> <a id="test" href="test.com">
        <div id="image">

        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#test {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#image {
    background: #000 url("http://www.veterinarian.com/uploads/cms/20100622/4c212d6c1ca11.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I marked this as correct, but instead of setting a background image, I still added the image.  Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bionicrm/RENFz/1/.  It's not perfect, but it comes pretty close to confining those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the link these styles

```
display:block;
width:100px; //or whatever you want
height:5em;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
```