# image link takes up width of column

Tags: html, css

This is very similar to [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223421/image-link-block-takes-up-whole-width-of-the-page) but that answer isn't working for me.

I have a row with images, and I want to the images to be clickable. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Education and Outreach</a></h2>
            <a href="#" style="width:225px;"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../img/outreach_small.JPG" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="Several remote-sensing-related words on a black background."></a>
            <br></br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Imagery</a></h2>
            <a href="#" style="width:225px;"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../img/earth.png" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="A satellite image of the Earth."></a>
            <br></br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Remote Sensing Resources</a></h2>
            <a href="#" style="width:225px;"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../img/dataresources.jpg" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="stylized stream of zeroes and ones emanating from a central globe."></a>
            <br></br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what I want it to look like. The red lines represent where the link boundaries should be-- i.e. only over the image (so that the images are clickable).

[image]

But instead the links are taking up the entire column width for each image. This is what the links currently look like (except without red lines):

[image]

I tried doing

```
<a href="#" style="width:225px; display=block;"><img class= ... [etc.]
```

with various "display" styles. But I could not get the image to be both centered within the column and not have the link overflowing over the image.

Comment: Remove inline width or instead use max-width

Comment: What do you mean by inline width? I don't see that anywhere in my code. Do you mean the `style="width:225px;"` code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are trying to make the `img` and `H2` clickable and to have each containing "cell" centred ensuring the text does not extend past the width of its image.

What I have done here is to remove the duplicate `a` and placed both the `h2` and the `img` inside the remaining `a`. 
By setting a `max-width` and `display:inline-block` on the `a`, you can ensure that the content does not expand.

```css
.col-lg-4 {display:inline-block;}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:225px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 align="center">Education and Outreach</h2>
              <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://via.placeholder.com/225x228" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="Several remote-sensing-related words on a black background.">
          </a>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#"><h2 align="center">Imagery</h2>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://via.placeholder.com/225x228" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="A satellite image of the Earth."></a>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="#"><h2 align="center">Remote Sensing Resources</h2>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://via.placeholder.com/225x228" style="width:225px;height:228px;" alt="stylized stream of zeroes and ones emanating from a central globe."></a>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't quite get me what I wanted, though. It forces everything in the column to align left: http://imgur.com/0TOuFS3.jpg Maybe I edited the wrong CSS file? I modified bootstrap.min.css, was I supposed to change a different CSS file?